# Run periodic task (frequently) while react native app in background

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have a react native app that runs while in background (it is playing an audio file).  I need to perform a task every 30 seconds (sending a message to a server to show progress through the audio playback) -- how can I arrange for that to happen?  At the moment, my app seems to stop processing events, timers, etc, as soon as it goes into the background.  I've found the module [react-native-background-timer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-timer), but that won't do the job because it won't run more often than every 15 minutes and I need to run every 30 seconds.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

react native offers https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android.html for android, but it has nothing for IOS, so you might have to write some native code